# How to dynamically overlay a set of grouped images from some folder

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose that we have a dataset of images where each image has the following structure:

```
foo1.png
foo1_cloud.png
foo1_full.png

foo2.png
foo2_cloud.png
foo2_full.png

...
```

Now, imagine that those images are all on a `somePath` folder, our issue is as follows. We want to take those sets of images (*i.e.*, the sets of `foo1` or `foo2` images), and overlay the images (*e.g.*, `foo1.png`, `foo1_cloud.png` and `foo1_full.png`). However, we would like to do this in a dynamic way. So that, for instance, each time we press a **Next** or **Previous** button we can iterate our image dataset across our `somePath/` folder.

At the moment, what we have is:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Content">
  <meta name="author" content="Content">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">

</head>

<body>
 <a href="#" class="previous">&#8249;</a>
 <img id="imgbase" src="somePath/foo1.png" />
 <img id="imgfull" src="somePath/foo1_full.png" />
 <img id="imgcloud" src="somePath/foo1_cloud.png" />
 <a href="#" class="next">&#8250;</a>
  <script src="scripts/server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

First of all, we need to query each image from the `somePath/` folder with respect to the file name. Therefore, we need to guarantee the file names (*e.g.*, `<filename>.png`, `<filename>_cloud.png` and `<filename>_full.png`), so that we can overlay the three files. Second, we need to provide the behaviour of the file update for the next or the previous file names.

So, our question is as follows:

**How can we dynamically overlay a set of grouped images from a folder?**